# Reduce space between elements in a css grid layout

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I have a grid layout that looks like this:

[image]

I would like to reduce the whitespace between 'Job Role' and 'Company Name' & I cannot work out how to do this.

The container css looks like this:

```css
.experience-child {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 2fr 6fr;
    grid-template-rows: repeat(5, 1fr);
    margin-bottom: 6em;
    font-family: 'Alumni Sans', sans-serif;
}
```

I have tried:

- Adjusting row-gap with `row-gap 0;`
- Adjusting margin-bottom and padding-bottom of the individual elements with negative values.
- Adding `grid-auto-rows: min-content;` to the above container

Thank you very much.

HTML & CSS to replicate:

```html
<div class="experience-child">
    <p class="years">2001-2001</p>
    <p class="jobrole">Job Role</p>
    <p class="company">Company Name</p>
    <ul class="job-blurb">
        <li>this</li>
        <li>that</li>
        <li>other</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

```css
.experience-child {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 2fr 6fr;
    grid-template-rows: repeat(5, 1fr);
    margin-bottom: 6em;
    font-family: 'Alumni Sans', sans-serif;
}

.last {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

.jobrole {
    font-weight: bold;
}

.company {
    grid-area: 2 / 2 / 3 / 3;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.job-blurb {
    grid-area: 3 / 2 / 5 / 3;
}
```

Comment: Please add an [example].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`grid-template-rows: repeat(5, 1fr);` indicates that your grid has 5 rows of equal height. That's the height of the `.experience-child` container divided by 5.

There are many ways to reduce the whitespace between **Job Role** and **Company Name**:

- You could reduce the height of the first row, by replacing it with e.g. `grid-template-rows: 1em repeat(4, 1fr);`
- You could keep equal row height and move **Job Role** within its container with e.g. `position: absolute; bottom: 0;`, or `padding-top: 1em;`
- You could place **Company Name** in the same container as **Job Role** by wrapping `<p class="jobrole">Job Role</p><p class="company">Company Name</p>` in a new `div`

Comment: Thank you, both answers worked - this one explained why a little better.

Answer (score 1):

Change `grid-template-rows: repeat(5, 1fr);` to `grid-template-rows: repeat(1, 1fr);`.

See the snippet below.

```css
.experience-child {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 2fr 6fr;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(1, 1fr);
  margin-bottom: 6em;
  font-family: 'Alumni Sans', sans-serif;
  background-color: gold;
}

.last {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.jobrole {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.company {
  grid-area: 2 / 2 / 3 / 3;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.job-blurb {
  grid-area: 3 / 2 / 5 / 3;
}

p {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="experience-child">
  <p class="years">2001-2001</p>
  <p class="jobrole">Job Role</p>
  <p class="company">Company Name</p>
  <ul class="job-blurb">
    <li>this</li>
    <li>that</li>
    <li>other</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, both answers worked but Dorins explained why a little better.